# Connecting Access DB to Excel and Vlookup

Tags: excel, ms-access, odbc, vlookup

I have an access file with over 3 milion records. I would would like that excel will be able to perfrom a vlookup serach in the access table and give me the result on excel. Any simple way to do that?

Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

That would be a terribly inefficient way to do it.

In a database you can use queries with JOINs to do this. If you tell us, what the table looks like and what you want to achieve, we can give you more info.

Comment: I have a table with:
Emp  year month salary - 3m records in a Access DB.
I want to build a tool for a user that will graph that data (He will enter employee number, year and will get a graph of salary during the year).
The problem : The user know excel only..

Comment: @oco: I see, so my answer was premature. Please add your additional info from the comment to your question (by editing it), then I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Andre451 said - you need SQL rather than Excel functions to get data out of the database.

This code will dump the query results into the immediate window.  It should show you how to extract data from Access though.
*Note* - I usually make the oDB variable global if I'm planning on querying the database a lot.  Also without knowing the name of your database or table structure I've just shown an example of the query used - you'll have to add code to get the employee number and year from the user.
*Tip* - Write your query in Access using the query editor, view it as SQL and then copy to Excel.

```
Sub ReturnValues()

    Dim oDB As Object
    Dim rst As Object

    Set oDB = GetDatabaseReference
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    With rst
        .CursorType = 2
        .Open "SELECT Salary FROM tbl_SomeTable WHERE Emp=1 AND Year=2015", oDB

        If Not rst Is Nothing Then
            If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
                .MoveFirst
                Do
                    Debug.Print rst.Fields("Salary")
                    .MoveNext
                Loop While Not .EOF
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub


Public Function GetDatabaseReference() As Object

    Dim cn As Object

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Only set a reference to the database if it doesn't already exist. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If oDB Is Nothing Then
        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Select Case Val(Application.Version)
            Case 11
                'Access 2003
                cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source =C:<Full Path To Database>.mdb;"

                    'Could use:
                    '"Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database\Database.mdb"
            Case 14
                'Access 2010
                cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source =C:<Full Path To Database>.mdb;" & _
                    "Persist Security Info=False;"

                    ''Could use:
                    '"Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database\Database.mdb;" & _
                    '"Persist Security Info=False;"
        End Select
        If Not cn Is Nothing Then
            Set GetDatabaseReference = cn
        End If
    Else
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'oDB already has a reference, so ensure it's maintained. '
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Set GetDatabaseReference = oDB
    End If

End Function
```